# Kibana: Display streaming logs with duration

Tags: streaming, duration, icecast, kibana

I have logs from a livestreaming-platform. They are written after a user has disconnected, they include (beside standard date/ip/useragent-information) a field called duration. it contains the seconds a user was connected to the stream.

I'd like to work with these logs in kibana. Getting them in is not a problem, but working with this duration-field is.

Is it possible to handle requests not as single events but as requests with a length?

thank you in advance
Chris

**Clarification**:
3 Example Loglines:

`x.46.19.144 - - [15/May/2014:23:45:54 +0200] "GET /m/1/mp3_128 HTTP/1.1" 200 50752 "-" "iTunes/9.1.1" 1480`

`x.35.46.107 - - [15/May/2014:23:50:55 +0200] "GET /m/2/aacp_96 HTTP/1.1" 200 1630430 "-" "Lavf52.111.0" 172`

`x.159.95.4 - - [15/May/2014:23:51:56 +0200] "GET /3/aacp_32 HTTP/1.1" 200 4875 "-" "Java/1.7.0_51" 268`

Id like to display them stacked, user1 started listening at 23:45 and stoped the playback 1480 seconds later, user2 started at :50 and hit stop 172seconds later, user 3 started one minute later at :51 and listened for 268 seconds
that should stack up to a graph which has 1 listener from 45, two at 50 and 3 at 51, and it goes back to 2 at about 56 an so on

Comment: Could you put an example of what you want to achieve, please?. I really don't understand what you are trying to do, sorry.

Comment: I've updated my question. I'd be happy if you have a hint for a possible solution to that question.

Comment: Please note that you are misinterpreting the access.log. The time-stamp is for when the client disconnects. So you have to count backwards to get the start time.